# THUMBNAIL GRID WITH EXPANDING PREVIEW - different preview heights for each item?

Tags: jquery, grid, thumbnails, preview

I’ve been struggling with having different preview heights for each item. 
Does anyone know how can we setHeights of the preview to be the height of the content?

At the moment it is being calculated acording to the window size.

This is the DEMO:
http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/

Thanks.